# How to capture everything (.*) inside tags, like e.g. [foo] Capture this [/foo] [foo] and this [/foo]

Tags: ruby, regex

Inside my string there a one or more occurrences of a tag starting with `[foo]` and ending with `[/foo]`. So imagine a string like this:

```
string = "[foo] Text inside tags [/foo] Text between tags [foo] Text inside tags [/foo]"
```

I want to capture the text inside each occurrence. If there were just one occurrence my regex could simply be:

```
regex = /\[foo\](.*)\[\/foo\]/
```

As anything could be inside the tags I have to capture it with `.*`. However by doing that I end up capturing everything between the first `[foo]` and the last `[/foo]`:

```
< string.scan(regex)
=> [[" Text inside tags [/foo] Text between tags [foo] Text inside tags "]]
```

[Link to the regex at Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/YEi6XOFgAg)

How do I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

Change your regular expression so you don't match "everything" but just match "everything except brackets":

```
\[foo\]([^\[\]]*?)\[\/foo\]
```

Comment: It's a duplicate so whatever, but what if you have an unmatched bracket? `[foo] like [ this [/foo]`

Comment: If you have an unmatched bracket, this approach breaks.

Comment: Yeah that could be the case, so any instance of `[` or `]` would break the regex. But wouldn't it be possible to change `([^\[\]]*?)` to something that don't just ban `[` and `]`, but `[/foo]`?

Comment: Sure, you can implement something using lookahead, like `\[foo\]((?:[^\[]|\[(?!\/foo))+?)\[\/foo\]`, which also allows an opening bracket unless it's followed by `/foo` inside.